# App crashes after receving phone call

Tags: android, crash, android-activity, oncreate

After I either receive a phone call or make one, (and other undocumented interruptions) my application gets a NullPointerException when resuming my activity. Can any explain to me where it is and/or how to fix it? When my activity resumes, it is calling onCreate it seems, and it is trying to execute something that is null after Resuming. How do I prevent onCreate() from being called?

My activity seems to terminate when I press the call button, because when I try to debug this error, the debugger disconnects.

EDIT:

So, how do I handle
process is killed -> onCreate() ? I have activities A -> B -> C -> D, and I press back all the way to A, there is no problem. But If I start another program, or another program comes to the foreground, D crashes, then C crashes, then B crashes, then A crashes!

EDIT:

I solved B,C,D crashing. It was because the class where I stored static variables was destroyed to free up resources, and my activities were getting null variables.

But when I get back to A, I get a classCastException:

```
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bookcessed.booksearch/com.bookcessed.booksearch.activities.ChooseProviderActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.widget.ProgressBar.onRestoreInstanceState(ProgressBar.java:944)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:6138)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1209)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1209)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:6117)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1466)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:843)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:815)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1096)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
08-13 16:52:10.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6048):     ... 11 more
```

Here is my onCreate():

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tempLayout = new RelativeLayout(ChooseProviderActivity.this);
        ProgressBar tempProgress = new ProgressBar(ChooseProviderActivity.this);
        tempProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
        tempProgress.setId(1); //I suspect this is the problem
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        tempLayout.addView(tempProgress, lp);
        setContentView(tempLayout);
```

This is where I think the problem lies:

```
tempProgress.setId(1); //I suspect this is the problem
```

Comment: What if someone calls your phone, but it's the wrong number?

Comment: Can you show your code for onCreate, and the exact stacktrace of the null pointer?

Comment: @recursive Haha yeah, they're already angry enough as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for other people's clarification, you do not need to assign ID's to Views that you instantiate in code. So you're code should work with just the

```
ProgressBar tempProgress = new ProgressBar(ChooseProviderActivity.this);
tempProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
tempLayout.addView(tempProgress, lp);
setContentView(tempLayout);
```

*Id's are only mainly when setting ID's in XML files, you assign it a string ID and the R.java is then compiled, and assigns each resource an ID number.* **Not entirely true!  See edit!**

**EDIT**

As superjos noted in the comments, you do need ID's when working with relative layouts.  Check out the docs on RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.addRule(int,int) for when you need ID's.

**END EDIT**

Like this...

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(SomeClass.this);
ll.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
TextView tv = new TextView(SomeClass.this);
EditText et = new EditText(SomeClass.this);
ll.add(tv);
ll.add(et);
```

This will have a textView above an EditText view.  In the other case...
doing

```
ll.add(et);
ll.add(tv);
```

will place the EditText ABOVE the TextView.  ID's have absolutely nothing to do with how they are laid out on the screen.

Comment: I thought you had to use it if you wanted to specify how objects should be layed out with respect to one another

Comment: No, how they are laid out is dependant on what LayoutParameters you set on a view and WHEN you add it to a viewgroup.  I edited my answer with some example code...

Comment: well, actually if you use relative layout then you probably end up using some Id, because some view needs to refer to some other view for its own positioning.

Comment: @superjos You are correct.  I'll modify my post to clarify that!

Comment: Hello..am extending service in my app..and it crashes after a phone call..how to i solve it

Comment: @PrathibhaKirthi This question is over 4 years old.  You'll get a better response by actually posting a new question with relevant details.

Comment: Hello @DavidAndroidDev..Thank you for your time..my app is working perfectly now..I don't know what was the exact reason for which it got crashed.That's why I didn't posted any question here

Answer (score 2):

Check out this image to see how and when the os will call your app. 
 [image]

Comment: So, how do I handle
process is killed -> onCreate() ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state

Answer (score 1):

Your app gets terminated for some reason, that's why onCreate is being called. You should save/resume application state to be able to handle this correctly. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state) and [developers reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your app uses too much memory so Android OS kills it in order to get enough memory to run another activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it again and don't attend a call or any process while your app is loading. Wait till it sets.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try and override all the basic functions which are used during the activity life cycle. use the adb logcat figure out with log.v where your error is occuring. Put one log after every line in the function in which the app crashes.

Also what are you calling from? are you calling from one emulator to the other? I have not had a problem with the log cat existing in such an instance.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a class with static variables and calling `.getStoredStaticVariable()` and `.saveStoredStaticVariable()` and when I would try to retrieve it, it would be null, probably because the class was being destroyed to free up resources.

EDIT: That was only partially the solution. The solution to the `ClassCastException()` was changing

```
tempProgress.setId(1);
```

to a number unlikely to be used by the system:

```
tempProgress.setId(6346346);
```